# String[] initialized by null?

Tags: java

Hi i encountered this problem whereby when i initialized my String[], there seems to be a null in the String[] before i do anything. How do i initialized the String[] to be completely empty,i.e. without the null at the start?
The output for the following code is:


`nullABC

nullABC

nullABC

nullABC

nullABC`

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] inputArr = new String[5];
    for (int i = 0; i< inputArr.length; i++){
        inputArr[i] += "ABC";
    }
    for (int i = 0; i< inputArr.length; i++){
        System.out.println(inputArr[i]);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A null reference is about as empty as a string array element can be. Note that there's a big difference between a reference to the empty string and a null reference though. Just change your code to use simple assignment instead of +=.

```
for (int i = 0; i< inputArr.length; i++){
    inputArr[i] = "ABC";
}
```

If you need to do conditional concatenation elsewhere, use something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i< inputArr.length; i++) {
    String current = inputArr[i];
    String suffix = "ABC";
    String replacement = current == null ? suffix : current + suffix;
    inputArr[i] = replacement;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use something like this:

```
public static String emptyForNull(String x) {
    return x == null ? "" : x;
}
```

and then have:

```
for (int i = 0; i< inputArr.length; i++){
    inputArr[i] = emptyForNull(inputArr[i]) + "ABC";
}
```

Or (yes, *lots* of available options):

```
public static String nullAwareConcat(String x, String y) {
    return x == null && y == null ? ""
        : x == null ? y
        : y == null ? x
        : x + y;
}

...

for (int i = 0; i< inputArr.length; i++){
    inputArr[i] = nullAwareConcat(inputArr[i], "ABC");
}
```

Comment: Holy mother...I think SkeetBot has gone into overdrive. :-P

Comment: Ahh thanks! the second part for concatenation is what i am looking for!

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
inputArr[i] += "ABC";
```

To:

```
inputArr[i] = "ABC";
```

Or (like Jon Skeet mentioned) you can use a conditional statement to either initialize or concat the strings:

```
inputArr[i] = inputArr[i] == null ? "ABC" : inputArr[i] + "ABC";
```

Answer (score 1):

The null in the array isn't the string `"null"`, but the value `null`. If you want to initialize it with empty strings, do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++) {
    inputArr[i] = "";
}
```

Comment: This is unnecessary, given the code in the question. Esmond is appending to the string in the array where he should be assigning to it.

Comment: Well, the question was "How do i initialized the String[] to be completely empty"...

Comment: @Thomas I'd agree with @Matti This could as well be just a bad example. I think what the OP meant with "completely empty" is an array of empty strings and that's what Matti stresses in his answer. But yes, otherwise it wouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Others gave pretty good answers concerning "emptiness" of an array and assignment operator. Just let me add another way to initialize an array:

```
String[] inputArr = new String[5];
java.util.Arrays.fill(inputArr, "ABC");
```